# best practice: general asmx data loading web-method or multi web-methods

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm wondering which is better approach from performance point of view, is it better to use one web-service method to load data by passing Database Table name and keys or is it better to use separate method for each database table! knowing that i'm using .net asmx through ajax requests.

it's obvious that one method is better from OO perspective since it have one function type 'data loading' but what about performance? does IIS affected by that or not? also is it better to make multi web-services 'asmx files' or just one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really dont think that creating separate methods for handling data fetch different tables is necessary. The performance gain\loss that u r likely to experience by passing an additional table name param to your webservice call would be too small to even consider unless your table names are really huge, which i dont think is the case.

The only reason i would even consider doing some thing like this is if i have nothing else to do in terms of performance improvement or if being forced to do it ;-).

If you really want to optimize your request size try

- serializing your input params using JSON (if you are not doing it already)
- use a cookieless domain for your webservice

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the service level should have any knowledge of database tables, just like you ideally don't want to see data access code in a controller action or ASPX's code behind.

Personally, I prefer to organize my services to match my domain model.

If I have `Customer`, `Order`, and `Item` classes, for example, I would have corresponding `Customer.asmx`, `Order.asmx`, and `Item.asmx` services to expose selected methods within those classes.

Comment: i didn't ask about how to organize! i don't access db tables directly but through BLL! so performance wise which better multi web methods or just one!

Comment: What did you mean by "use one web-service method to load data by passing Database Table name and keys" then?  There's no significant performance difference.  If anything, overloading a single method with a dispatch system would be slower than using single-purpose methods.

Comment: db table names and keys just easy words for those who doesn't use layers architect [just to get bigger general users base to answer] but sure that's not how i pass them. and i don't overload, for example, why you use different asmx foreach class while you could make only one, instead of implementing loading method foreach of customers, orders, items lists you can use DB-Factory structure and pass the class name with the required params and that's it. this what i use as architecture. anyway thanks for trying!

Comment: In practice, that gets complex quick. You'll inevitably end up with varying differences between domain objects and view models, ranging from model -> view model transforms to individual tweaks for display (converting DateTime dates to .ToShortDateString() to avoid dealing with the lack of a Date literal in JSON is a common one there).  Trying to build a single service endpoint flexible enough to handle all of those per-usage needs always ends up being an overly complex nightmare (just look at the path Astoria has taken, for example).  Guaranteed to be slower than single-purpose [WebMethod]s.

Answer (score 0):

Services are typically responsible for exposing business functionality through a contract. I realize ASMX services really had not concept of "Contracts" in their broadest sense, however you think of it as a set of operations supported by the service. What is your goal here, do you want to expose tabular data as a service ?

Service technology on the Microsoft stack has come a long way from ASMX. Perhaps an obvious question, have you looked at WCF Data Services?

Links:

- [Exposing Your Data as a Service (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728286.aspx)
- [Getting Started with WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668810.aspx)

Comment: Since he's talking about using the services as endpoints for AJAX callbacks, sticking with ASMX isn't a bad choice (at least until this next WCF update).  For all the extra hassle that comes with dealing with WCF, the only thing it really brings to the table for AJAX callbacks is its *less* flexible DCJS serializer.

Comment: i love wcf but no space/time to update for the current project. and my question is not about data its about performance and best practice of using ASMX single web-method VS multi web-methods through AJAX requests!